# Registering classes/functions/things before main()

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class called Poem.

```
class Poem{
   virtual void recite() = 0;
}
```

And I have hundreds of .cpp and .hpp files which describe a subclass, like the following

```
class TheRaven : public Poem{
    void recite() { std::cout << "NEVERMORE!" << endl; }
}
```

And the likes. And in the main function, I'd like to be able to just iterate through every single possible Poem subclasses and call their recite() function. So I made a class:

```
class PoemRegistry{
    std::map<std::string, Poem*> poems;
    PoemRegistry& getGlobal(); // returns a static global registry
    void register(const std::string& poemname, Poem * thepoem);
};
```

And then for each poem subclass .cpp file, I put the following.

```
class TheRavenRegistor{
    TheRavenRegistor(){
        PoemRegistry::getGlobal().register("theraven", new TheRaven());
    }
}
TheRavenRegistor registor();
```

**ninja edit**: I put the global class there, forgot about it

Making it easy, I make a shortcut with #define and templates.

Now, the question is, I just heard about the static class initialization fiasco. I suppose this will be immune against it, or is there something I am definitely missing here? Or is there something more elegant that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: What is the purpose ? Do you want to call `recite()` for every global object which is initialized before `main()` ?

Comment: When does `TheRavenRegistor` get instantiated?

Comment: Something is missing from your code above, as there is nothing to statically initialize.

Comment: yes, forgot about it, now it's there, my bad. @iammilind: Yes, suppose that is the purpose. It could be that I need to have a list of available poems, and recite any of them by user's choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example for the *Singleton design pattern*. Don't use a static global, since the initialisation order is undefined across compilation units.
Instead use something like this:

```
PoemRegistry& PoemRegistry::getGlobal()
{
  static PoemRegistry theRegistry; // construction guaranteed when first call
  return theRegistry;
}
```

Make the getGlobal() method `static`:

```
class PoemRegistry
{
public:
  static PoemRegistry& getGlobal();
...
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot about the static keyword, but that was the idea.